# CSS to multiple mat-cards responsive

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, mat-card

I have a project in Angular material in which I am creating a component with several mat-cards. What I am trying to do is make the screen responsive depending on the width of the cards.

Right now only the card is made smaller but not the titles or the content. And all the cards appear in a single column.

This is my component.html:

```
<div class="container">
      <mat-card *ngFor="let properties of menuComponent.fillerNav" class = "mat-elevation-z4">
        <mat-card-header>
          <mat-card-title>
            {{properties.name}}
            <mat-icon class="iconMenu">{{properties.icon}}</mat-icon>
          </mat-card-title>
        </mat-card-header>
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <mat-card-content>
          <p>
            total
          </p>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
</div>
```

This is my component.scss:

```
mat-card {
  width: 20%
}
```

This is the view of the window with F12:

[image]

Comment: Try to use `.flex-me {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  
}`

Comment: See how to [Create a responsive card grid in Angular using Flex Layout](https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/create-a-responsive-card-grid-in-angular-using-flex-layout-part-1/)

Comment: @I_Al-thamary I have already been testing that page but I can't make it work for my html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it work on  HTML  try it this way

```
.flex-me 
{   display: inline-flex; 
  flex-flow: row wrap;    
}
mat-card{
    width: fit-content;
}
```

Also here is a full example [how  to create a responsive card grid in Angular using Flex Layout](https://zoaibkhan.com/blog/create-a-responsive-card-grid-in-angular-using-flex-layout-part-1/)